# How to calculate the Pareto distribution with m=0

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, bayesian, density-function

I am trying to calculate the Pareto distribution where the random variable has this range: $0 \le x \le \infty$

The book I found the Pareto distribution in has defined it like so:

$Pareto(x|m,k) = k \times m^{k} \times x^{-(k+1)} \times I(x \ge m)$

where $I(true) = 1$ and $I(false) = 0$

The book also has a few example graphs:

[image: Pareto_graphs]

**My question is this:** it appears that the $m$ is the lower limit of the range of the random variable, and I would like to set mine to zero (like the red dotted line in the plots above). The only problem is that when $m$ in the formula for Pareto is set to zero, the whole thing ends up being zero ... so how did they obtain the red dotted line plot (which is clearly not zero everywhere)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That $\operatorname{Pareto}(0 \mid 0, k) = 0$ is not a problem, but it is what it should be. And if you look at the red dotted line at $x = 0$, you observe that the value is $0$. So, there is nothing wrong here.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich  the horizontal axis does not plot m, but rather it plots x.  When I set m=0, the line is zero all the way (as per the zero constant in the formula). But the red dotted line is also plotted with m=0, yet it is not zero the whole way .... look what happens to it as it gets close to zero

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich  could you please tell me why "m=0.00" in the key in the top right corner of the screenshot, yet the red dotted line is not zero the whole way? Thanks in advance

Comment: You are right. I misundetstood you. The red line should be zero everywhere, not only at zero.

Comment: There is a disconnect between the curves and the Pareto Type I distribution. For example, the red dashed curve could be a Pareto Type III distribution, but not a Type I. Either the book is being misquoted or it is incorrect. Please provide the book citation and/or more complete text.

Comment: @Carl note the legend appears to be rounded off to two decimal places and the red plot does appear to got to zero at a very small value.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen For Type IV the limit from the right $\underset{x\to 0^+}{\text{lim}}f(x)=\infty$ and from the left $\underset{x\to 0^-}{\text{lim}}f(x)=0$, that is, when $\gamma>1$.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen If $m=0.00>0$, then it could be Pareto distribution Type I, but  that would be misleading and sloppy. For example, I cannot see the difference between the plot in my answer, which is Type IV, and the plot in the question, which is why I really want to see the original text. Also, I answered the question, which is "How one can have $m=0$."

Comment: @Carl Their plot starts from zero... yours starts from to the left of zero.Besides that I just don't think them plotting a Pareto type IV is plausible considering OP gives the distribution they claim to use (a type I) and the legend only has those two parameters. I think 'they set the m parameter very close to zero but the legend rounded off to zero' is much more plausible than 'they chose a completely different functional form and didn't label the parameters correctly'. (They also could have made a completely different mistake).

Comment: @Carl Here: Under suspicion that maybe they used m=.001 (since they used multiples of 10 for the other). I plotted both of them (couldn't figure out how to do the cutoff on this thing but it's invisibly close to the origin anyway). Looks very close if not identical https://www.desmos.com/calculator/d35ur8mnsz

Comment: @Carl As I said before, you gave one of many possibilities to regulate the divergence while letting the domain extend to zero. Yours does have the feature that the PDF diverges at the origin, but contrary to what you say, I don't see how that requirement is requested in the OP, or even implied. Which is not to say it isn't potentially interesting.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen The title question reads, "How to calculate the Pareto distribution with m=0?" which if it was not meant to be asked, shouldn't have been. I would really rather see the source material, but, that is the question I answered. The "how to" requires a general Pareto distribution, or it is not longer Pareto at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set the lower limit to zero. The reason is that the integral $\int_0^a x^{-(k+1)}dx $ diverges at the lower endpoint (for $k\ge 0$). This means the distribution can't be defined with support going all the way down to zero.

That said, there are other ways to regulate the divergence than just taking a hard cutoff value. For instance you could include a convergence factor $e^{-m/x}$ in the density and then take the support $0<x<\infty$. That would be a distribution that is similar to the Pareto (for $x\gg m$) but has support on all the positive reals. However note that the density drops sharply for $x<m$. You aren't really eliminating the cutoff, just smoothing it out a bit.

Comment: What should the relationship between **m** and **k** be so that when integrated from m to infinity, it equals 1?

Comment: @Josh the normalization coefficient $km^k$ for the Pareto distribution is selected so that it integrates to one. So it will equal one for any $m>0$ and $k>0$. They don't need to satisfy any relationship.

Comment: Agreed, one cannot use a Pareto distribution Type I as the discontinuity is not integrable. However, one can use Type III or IV for that purpose and the discontinuity is then integrable, see answer.

Comment: @Carl Yes, there's tons of ways to soften the divergence at the origin if you want the support to start at $0$ for some reason. I suggested an exponential cutoff. Using a pareto type 4 (which interpolates to an integrable power law divergence for $\gamma > 1$) also would work, as would just using something of the form $1/(1+x)^{\alpha+1}$ which would go to a constant. Usually, we really don't care about the origin behavior, just about the power law tail.

Answer (score 1):

One way around this is to use the [Pareto distribution](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParetoDistribution.html) Type II with  the mean set to zero, which is called the Lomax distribution.
The PDF for this is 
$$\begin{array}{cc}
 \Bigg\{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \dfrac{\alpha}{k}  \left(\dfrac{k+x}{k}\right)^{-\alpha -1} & x\geq 0 \\
 0 & \text{Elsewhere} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$$

Or, to alternatively use Pareto Types III or IV. A solution for Type IV is shown here. The Pareto distribution Type IV pdf is,

$$
f(k,\alpha,\gamma,\mu;x)=\begin{array}{cc}
 \Bigg\{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{\alpha  k^{-1/\gamma } (x-\mu )^{\frac{1}{\gamma }-1} \left(\left(\frac{k}{x-\mu }\right)^{-1/\gamma }+1\right)^{-\alpha -1}}{\gamma } & x\geq \mu  \\
 0 & \text{Elsewhere} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$$

And, then set the location parameter, $\mu$, to zero, which yields

$$f(k,\alpha,\gamma,0;x)=\begin{array}{cc}
 \Bigg\{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{\alpha  k ^{-1/\gamma } x^{\frac{1}{\gamma }-1} \left(\left(\frac{k }{x}\right)^{-1/\gamma }+1\right)^{-\alpha -1}}{\gamma } & x\geq 0 \\
 0 & \text{Elsewhere} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
$$

Next, when $\gamma>1$ the limit as $x\rightarrow0^+$ is $\infty$, which is what was requested, with the difference from the ordinary Pareto distribution (Type I) being that the discontinuity at $x=0$ is now integrable whereas the Pareto distribution Type I cannot take an $x=0$ as in that case the discontinuity at $x=0$ would not be integrable, i.e., the cdf would be infinite. For all values of $\gamma$ the Type IV cdf exists for $x\geq0$ and is

$$F(k,\alpha,\gamma,0;x)=\begin{array}{cc}
 \Bigg\{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 1-\left(\left(\frac{x}{k }\right)^{1/\gamma }+1\right)^{-\alpha } & x\geq 0 \\
 0 & \text{Elsewhere} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
$$

A plot of the Type IV solution quite similar to the OP plot is shown below as the red dashed curve. That its cdf now exists is illustrated as the blue dotted curve.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use change of variable? Let $X\sim\;$Pareto($m,k$) and define $Y=X-m$. Hence, the density function of $Y$ is $$f_Y(y|m,k)=f_X(y+m|m,k)=\dfrac{km^k}{(y+m)^{k+1}}I(y\geq 0).$$